# How to dismiss the UIAlertview on the click of UIViewController or on the UIScrollView in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am new in iOS and I am facing the problem regarding to dismiss the UIAlertview. I am showing Image in UIAlertview and I am using long press gesture to call the alertview. My code is like this

```
ImageName.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressgestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [longpressgestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(imgLongPressed:)];
    longpressgestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [ImageName addGestureRecognizer: longpressgestureRecognizer];

- (void) imgLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 282)];
    UIImage *wonImage = ImageName.image;
    imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [imageView setImage:wonImage];
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                        message:@""
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    //check if os version is 7 or above
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        [alertView setValue:imageView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    }else{
        [alertView addSubview:imageView];
    }
    [alertView show];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:1.0];
}


-(void)dismiss:(UIAlertView*)alert
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
}
```

This code give me output like this Image

[image]

I need to dismiss the UIAlertview on the touch of UIViewController or UIScrollView.

Comment: Well, `UIAlertView` is deprecated (`UIAlertController`), you shouldn't play with its subview since iOS7 (that's why you have a specific code for it btw). Are you sure you want to keep in that direction? Not that you may want to add a userInteractionEnabled to YES for your UIImageView.

Comment: @Larme Yes I want to keep it in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertView` is depreciated. It is generally not advised to use depreciated elements since they might cause some problems with latest versions of iOS. For the given functionality, I think it's better to use thirdparty AlertViews like this one: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SCLAlertView-Objective-C